# Hololens - Access Camera Frames

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-capture, hololens

How can I access all frames in a video stream from the hololens camera, when in 3D mode? I'm using C#.

The unity `VideoCapture` class doesn't seem to provide this:
http://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/VR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html

and the microsoft `MediaCapture` class with method `MediaCapture.StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync` is not very well documented.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the MediaCapture FrameReader API

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader#create-a-frame-reader-for-the-frame-source

Sample code:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames

Comment: @yokto  does it work with hololens and if yes can you please guide me with sample code?

Answer (score 4):

We made an open source project called [CameraStream](https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream) to address this need. As a Unity plugin, it uses MediaCapture to feed the byte array into Unity (along with locatable matrices). From there you can assign the bytes to a Texture2D, as shown in the provided Unity example.

Our VideoCapture class mimic's [Unity's class of the same name](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html) so that developers would be familiar with how to use it. We're also assuming that this functionality will be provided by Unity out-of-the-box eventually.

Comment: You're the MVP I was looking for. I can't believe I came across that answer right when it was posted... Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @Eric Smith: Now we have 2020, do you know if there is some way of getting the raw video stream pixels?

Comment: @Eric Smith: Does your open source project also provide a way of getting the Video + the rendered 3D content? I would like to be able to stream a video with what the Hololens user sees.